# Long execution time for each request ApiPlatform

Tags: docker, symfony, api-platform.com, odm

I use symfony + api platform, but the execution time of each request is over 4 seconds. Tell me what additional information I can provide

**Screen:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuCs0.png)

I tried to find a similar problem, but in reality everything is too individual.

**app.ini**

```
variables_order = EGPCS
expose_php = 0
date.timezone = UTC
apc.enable_cli = 1
session.use_strict_mode = 1
zend.detect_unicode = 0
memory_limit = 2048M
realpath_cache_size = 4096K
realpath_cache_ttl = 600
opcache.interned_strings_buffer = 16
opcache.max_accelerated_files = 20000
opcache.memory_consumption = 256
opcache.enable_file_override = 1
```

**security.yaml**

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            mongodb:
                class: App\Document\User
                property: login
    firewalls:
        profiler:
            pattern: ^/(_profiler|_wdt)
            http_basic:
                realm: Secured Area

        dev:
            pattern: ^/(css|images|js)/
            security: false
        api:
            pattern: ^/
            stateless: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            lazy: true
            entry_point: jwt
            json_login:
                check_path: login_check
                username_path: login
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            jwt: ~
            refresh_jwt:
                check_path: refresh_token
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/_profiler, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/register, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/docs, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4
                time_cost: 3
                memory_cost: 10
```

Comment: Hard to help without an indication of your code. Please share a minimal setup that reproduces this problem.

Comment: @datawookie, what information should I attach?

Comment: You have tagged this as `docker`, so perhaps the `Dockerfile`? Basically you need to provide sufficient information for somebody to be able to replicate your problem. I don't know much about Symfony, so definitely need more context to make sense of this. Possibly somebody with more background wouldn't need it. Happy to try help though with more information.